# Webpack Refuses to Parse My JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, html, npm, webpack

I am new to webpack and am just trying to get it actually work. I haven't found anyone else with my issue, but everytime I try to npm run build which runs webpack I get an error saying:

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\bradr\OneDrive\Desktop\repos\weather-app\src\index.js: Unexpected character '�'. (1:0)

Index.js file

```
import { heythere } from "./generateJoke";

console.log(123);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

First I thought maybe I have made a mistake in my code or in following the tutorial but I did it again the same error came up. Then I started googling and thought maybe I could change the webpack.config.js file.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "/src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

but nothing is working, every little tweak I make is the same error.

Comment: Did you copy/paste something into your code? The error you are getting is not some kind of mistake; there really is a weird character in your code. You might try erasing the first couple of lines with your text editor and then type them back in manually.

Comment: I havent copy and pasted anything into the code and no matter what I type the beginning of the file is seen as an unrecognizable character. I leads me to believe the the loader doesn't recognize it as javascipt, but I have specifically configured the webpack file to recognize js and use the loader.

Comment: Somebody had this same issue a year ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72608066/webpack-5-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character-10 - I'm going to guess it's coming from `generateJoke` - since both questions have that in common at the same line `1:0` - EDIT: Looks like you found the solution in the file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times error like that means that your file has some bytes that are not displayed as visible characters in text editors:

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.en

> Some applications insert a particular combination of bytes at the beginning of a file to indicate that the text contained in the file is Unicode. This combination of bytes is known as a signature or Byte Order Mark (BOM). Some applications - such as a text editor or a browser - will display the BOM as an extra line in the file, others will display unexpected characters, such as ï»¿.

You can check your file's encoding in Encoding menu of Notepad++, for example.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. My encoding is set to UTF-8 on vs code. So this was not the issue.

Comment: HAHA you did lead me in the right direction, turns out my file was actually deciding to encode itself in UTF-16 LE even though my setting do UTF-8 by default. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my file was encoding its self in UTF-16 LE instead of the defualt UTF-8 that I had set, thus making the file unreadable by the transpiler.